# Change two lines in text

Tags: python, file-io, editing

I have a python script mostly coded so far for a project I'm currently working on and have hit a road block.  I essentially run a program that spits out the following output file (called big.dmp):

```
)O+_05 Big-body initial data  (WARNING: Do not delete this line!!)
) Lines beginning with `)' are ignored.
)---------------------------------------------------------------------
  style (Cartesian, Asteroidal, Cometary) = Cartesian
  epoch (in days) =    1365250.
)---------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPSTAR r=5.00000E-01 d=3.00000E+00  m= 0.160000000000000E+01
  4.570923967127310E-01  1.841433531828977E+01  0.000000000000000E+00
 -6.207379670518027E-03  1.540861575481520E-04  0.000000000000000E+00
  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00
```

Now with this file I need to edit both the epoch line and the line beginning with COMPSTAR while keeping the rest of the information constant from integration to integration as the last 3 lines contain the cartesian coordinates of my object and is essentially what the program is outputting.

I know how to use `f = open('big.dmp', 'w')` and `f.write('text here')` to create the initial file but how would one go about reading these final three lines into a new big.dmp file for the next integration?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
infile = open('big1.dmp')
outfile = open('big2.dmp', 'w')

for line in infile:
    if line.startswith(')'):
        # ignore comments
        pass
    elif 'epoch' in line:
        # do something with line
        line = line.replace('epoch', 'EPOCH')
    elif line.startswith('COMPSTAR'):
        # do something with line
        line = line.replace('COMPSTAR', 'comparison star')
    outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

On the off-chance that the *format* of your file is *fixed* with regard to line numbers, this solution will change only the two lines:

```
with open('big.dmp') as inf, open('out.txt', 'w') as outf:
    data = inf.readlines()
    data[4] = '  epoch (in days) = 9999.\n'      # line with epoch
    data[6] = 'COMPSTAR r=2201 d=3330  m= 12\n'  # line with COMPSTAR
    outf.writelines(data)
```

resulting in this output file:

```
)O+_05 Big-body initial data  (WARNING: Do not delete this line!!)
) Lines beginning with `)' are ignored.
)---------------------------------------------------------------------
  style (Cartesian, Asteroidal, Cometary) = Cartesian
  epoch (in days) = 9999.
)---------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPSTAR r=2201 d=3330  m= 12
  4.570923967127310E-01  1.841433531828977E+01  0.000000000000000E+00
 -6.207379670518027E-03  1.540861575481520E-04  0.000000000000000E+00
  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00
```

Clearly this will *not* work if the line numbers aren't consistent, but I thought I'd offer it up just in case your data format is consistent in terms of line numbers.

Also, since it reads the whole file into memory at once, it won't be an ideal solution for truly huge files.

The advantage of opening files using `with` is that they are automatically closed for you when you are done with them, or if you encounter an exception.

There are more flexible solution (searching for the strings, processing the file line-by-line) but if your data is fixed and small, there's no downside of taking advantage of those factors. Somebody smart once said "Simple is better than complex." (The Zen of Python)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat more change-tolerant version:

```
import re

reg_num = r'\d+'
reg_sci = r'[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?'

def update_config(s, finds=None, replaces=None, **kwargs):
    if finds is None:    finds = update_config.finds
    if replaces is None: replaces = update_config.replaces

    for name,value in kwargs.iteritems():
        s = re.sub(finds[name], replaces[name].format(value), s)
    return s

update_config.finds = {
    'epoch': r'epoch \(in days\) =\s*'+reg_num+'\.',
    'r':     r' r\s*=\s*' + reg_sci,
    'd':     r' d\s*=\s*' + reg_sci,
    'm':     r' m\s*=\s*' + reg_sci
}
update_config.replaces = {
    'epoch': 'epoch (in days) ={:>11d}.',
    'r':     ' r={:1.5E}',
    'd':     ' d={:1.5E}',
    'm':     ' m= {:1.15E}'
}

def main():
    with open('big.dmp') as inf:
        s = inf.read()

    s = update_config(s, epoch=1365252, r=0.51, d=2.99, m=1.1)

    with open('big.dmp', 'w') as outf:
        outf.write(s)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what you want, but assuming that you only want to remove the lines not starting with ):

```
text = open(filename).read()
lines = text.split("\n")
result = [line for line in lines if not line.startswith(")")
```

or, the one liner:

```
[line for line in open(file_name).read().split("\n") if not line.startswith(")")]
```